# powershellで特定文字列があれば変換。具体的には'13.1'だけを '5'へ変換したい

Tags: powershell

powershellで'13.1'だけを '5'へ変換するつもりで下記コードを書いたのですが、

```
$hoge = $hoge -replace '13.1', '5'
```

実際に試したら「13.1」だけではなく「1341」も「5」へ変換されてしまいました。
「13.1」だけを「5」へ変換するためにはどう書けばよいですか？

環境
Windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hoge = $hoge -replace '13\.1', '5'
```

とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: 変更したら期待通り動作したのですが、なぜエスケープが必要なのですか？ powershellは常に「.」にエスケープが必要？　それとも文字列操作だから？？

Comment: 文字列操作が正規表現扱いされているからだと思います。

Comment: なるほど、参考になりました